# ElasticSearch Significant Terms Aggregation: doc_count and bg_count unequal for search term

Tags: elasticsearch, significant-terms

I'm unsure here if there is something incorrect with my query, my document structure, or my interpretation of the `doc_count` and `bg_count` fields.

When running a significant terms aggregation and sorting results by score, the search term is always, understandably, first on that list. However, I would expect that the `doc_count` and `bg_count` would match for the search term, because I understand the `doc_count` to be the number of documents that match both the key and the filter term, and the background count to be the number of documents that match the filter term. So in the case where the filer term is the key, `doc_count` and `bg_count` would be equal.

Instead I see in general that the `doc_count` is lower than the `bg_count` and the score is (significantly) less than 1.

As an example:

```
{
"size" : 0,
"timeout" : 1800000,
"query" : {
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : {
      "has_child" : {
        "query" : {
          "term" : {
            "item_id" : 2606
          }
        },
        "child_type" : "item"
      }
    }
  }
},
"aggregations" : {
  "st_agg" : {
    "children" : {
      "type" : "item"
    },
    "aggregations" : {
      "items" : {
        "significant_terms" : {
          "field" : "item_id",
          "size" : 500,
          "exclude" : [ "51713398" ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

For these queries, I am not using a background filter. This is on ElasticSearch 2.3.2 (Don't judge, upgrade to 6.x is underway).

Is this expected?

Comment: Can you add your actual query and the results?

Comment: I've added an example query.